# Reading Simple Data Into a Variable Using NFC on Android

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, android-applicationrecord

I am making a simple Android application.  The primary function is, I want to read in data from an NFC tag.  I already have the basic app built (not much more than the Hello World app).  I'm using Eclipse.  I have the Android Application Record on the tag, and the app successfully launches when my tag is scanned.  I'm just not sure how to continue.  I need to:

- In addition to the AAR, have a four digit number stored in the tag.
- When the tag is scanned, have the app open and the four digit number stored in a local variable (using intent I think?).

Any help appreciated, as well as the simplest code possible that'll get the job done.  This is my first Android app and first time using Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your launcher Activity you should check the intent type if it is the same as you stored in the tag - getIntent.getType(). Then you can read data from the tag using this code:

```
Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
NdefMessage msg = (NdefMessage)rawMsgs[0];
NdefRecord cardRecord = msg.getRecords()[0];
String message = new String(cardRecord.getPayload());
```

If its a number, then you need to parse it from message.
I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you.  So would this go in the onCreate function in my mainActivity so that it runs when the app gets launched by the tag?

Comment: Do I need to make any changes to the manifest for this to work?

Comment: Yes, onCreate in main Activity. You need to add nfc permission in manifest: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" /> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html